# Glassfish change JDBC Pool from localhost to 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, glassfish

This is my JDBC Connection Pool configuration:

```
<jdbc-connection-pool max-pool-size="300" steady-pool-size="3" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" name="teDS" wrap-jdbc-objects="false" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
  <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"></property>
  <property name="port" value="3306"></property>
  <property name="DatabaseName" value="db"></property>
  <property name="serverName" value="localhost"></property>
  <property name="password" value="XXX"></property>
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"></property>
  <property name="user" value="user"></property>
</jdbc-connection-pool>
```

PLEASE HELP ME

But I PING connection have this error:

An error has occurred
Ping Connection Pool failed for teDS. Connection could not be allocated because: Access denied for user 'user'@'**127.0.0.1**' (using password: YES) Please check the server.log for more details.

[Ping ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H3W1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user in MySQL is identified by a username AND a host.

To allow a connection, we need to create a user in MySQL that has a matching username and host. To create a user that is an exact match:

```
 GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'supersecretpassword' ;
 GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON somedatabase.* TO 'user'@'127.0.0.1' ;
```

To replicate the privileges of an existing user, we could make use of a SHOW GRANTS statement to extract privileges for some other user

```
 SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'localhost'
```

We can copy the output from that, and use that as a basis for GRANT statements for the new user, replacing 'localhost' with '127.0.0.1'.

As another option, it's also possible to create a user with a '%' wildcard for a hostname, rather than '127.0.0.1'. That would allow connections from any IP address.

---

If the user exists, then the password could be wrong. Verify that the password the pool configuration is using matches what is stored in the mysql.user table.

```
SELECT password FROM mysql.user WHERE user = 'user' and host = '127.0.0.1';

SELECT PASSWORD('supersecretpassword') ;
```

And compare the hash values.

The error message that is being returned looks like it is from MySQL server:

> Access denied for user 'user'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

That makes is appear that a successful TCP handshake through port 3306 has happened, and MySQL Server is attempting to authenticate: user='user', host='127.0.0.1', and password=PASSWORD('XXX').

Either the user doesn't exist in the mysql.user table, the password is incorrect, or (possibly) the user doesn't have privileges on database='db'.

(If DML changes were applied to the privileges table in the mysql database, issue a FLUSH PRIVILEGES to make those changes effective. (FLUSH PRIVILEGES isn't required if changes are applied using GRANT and REVOKE syntax, only required if changes are applied using INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE.)